# Merge unique elements from two arrays

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, c, arrays

I have two arrays

```
array1 = { 2 , 4 , 1 , 5 , 7 , 10 } ;

array2 = { 3 , 1 , 6 , 8 , 9 , 4 };
```

My resultant array should be unique elements from both arrays, i.e

```
Result = { 2 , 5 , 7 , 10 , 3 , 6 , 8 , 9 };
```

Conditions: Arrays will be unsorted integer values.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because SO is not a code writing service, please demonstrate ideas, attempts and where your code doesn't work

Comment: @EdChum How can he demonstrate ideas if he has no ideas?!:)

Answer (score 3):

Sort the arrays, then do [std::set_symmetric_difference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_symmetric_difference) on them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straightforward approach using standard algorithms

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    int a1[] = { 2 , 4 , 1 , 5 , 7 , 10 } ;
    int a2[] = { 3 , 1 , 6 , 8 , 9 , 4 };

    for ( int x : a1 ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( int x : a2 ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    size_t n = std::count_if( std::begin( a1 ), std::end( a1 ),
        [&]( int x )
        {
            return
            std::find( std::begin( a2 ), std::end( a2 ), x ) == std::end( a2 );
        });

    n += std::count_if( std::begin( a2 ), std::end( a2 ),
        [&]( int x )
        {
            return
            std::find( std::begin( a1 ), std::end( a1 ), x ) == std::end( a1 );
        });

    int *result = new int[n];
    int *p = result;

    p = std::copy_if( std::begin( a1 ), std::end( a1 ), p,
        [&]( int x )
        {
            return
            std::find( std::begin( a2 ), std::end( a2 ), x ) == std::end( a2 );
        });

    std::copy_if( std::begin( a2 ), std::end( a2 ), p,
        [&]( int x )
        {
            return
            std::find( std::begin( a1 ), std::end( a1 ), x ) == std::end( a1 );
        });

    for ( p = result; p != result + n; ++p ) std::cout << *p << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    delete [] result;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
2 4 1 5 7 10 
3 1 6 8 9 4 
2 5 7 10 3 6 8 9
```

instead of for example `std::begin( a1 )` and `std::end( a1 )` you can write simply `a1` and `a1 + 6` where 6 is the size of a1.

If you are allowed to sort the original arrays then the program could look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    int a1[] = { 2 , 4 , 1 , 5 , 7 , 10 } ;
    int a2[] = { 3 , 1 , 6 , 8 , 9 , 4 };

    for ( int x : a1 ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( int x : a2 ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::sort( std::begin( a1 ), std::end( a1 ) );
    std::sort( std::begin( a2 ), std::end( a2 ) );

    size_t n = std::count_if( std::begin( a1 ), std::end( a1 ),
        [&]( int x )
        {
            return
            !std::binary_search( std::begin( a2 ), std::end( a2 ), x );
        } );

    n += std::count_if( std::begin( a2 ), std::end( a2 ),
        [&]( int x )
        {
            return
            !std::binary_search( std::begin( a1 ), std::end( a1 ), x );
        } );

    int *result = new int[n];

    std::set_symmetric_difference( std::begin( a1 ), std::end( a1 ),
                                   std::begin( a2 ), std::end( a2 ),
                                   result );

    for ( int *p = result; p != result + n; ++p ) std::cout << *p << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    delete [] result;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
2 4 1 5 7 10 
3 1 6 8 9 4 
2 3 5 6 7 8 9 10
```